# How to create different instances of decorator class in python

Tags: python, decorator

I am currently trying to implement a decorator class to keep track of function calls within the waiter class that I have 2 instances of. I want the 2 waiter instances to have separate instances of the decorator class to keep track of calls on each of them, is this possible?

Code:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
import time

class decorater():
    """
    counts the number of calls and passes it into function
    """
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
        self.num_calls = 0
        update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.num_calls += 1
        result = self.func(self.num_calls, *args, **kwargs) # passes num_calls in for seconds
        print(f"total runs of {self.func.__name__}: {self.num_calls}")
        return result
    
class waiter():
    """
    waits for the number of seconds passed in
    """
    @decorater
    def wait_for(seconds, var_name):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        print(f"{var_name} waited for {seconds} seconds")

waiter1 = waiter()
waiter2 = waiter()

waiter1.wait_for("waiter1")
waiter2.wait_for("waiter2")
```

Output:

```
waiter1 waited for 1 seconds
total runs of wait_for: 1
waiter2 waited for 2 seconds
total runs of wait_for: 2
```

Desired output:

```
waiter1 waited for 1 seconds
total runs of wait_for: 1
waiter2 waited for 1 seconds
total runs of wait_for: 1
```

Comment: This structure seems weird. Why is `wait_for` an instance method if it doesn't use `self` at all?

Comment: Oh wait, it's not actually an instance method, it's a `decorater` object. Even more confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Decorators are not really supposed to be used how you are trying to use them, and because you are already creating multiple instances of the `waiter` class, why not just handle everything inside of each of those instances instead of using a decorator?

Something like this:

```
import time


class Waiter(object):
    """
    waits for the number of seconds passed in
    """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.num_calls = 0

    def wait(self):
        self.num_calls += 1
        print(f"total runs of {self.num_calls}")

        time.sleep(self.num_calls)
        print(f"{self.name} waited for {self.num_calls} seconds")


waiter1 = Waiter("waiter1")
waiter2 = Waiter("waiter2")

waiter1.wait()
waiter2.wait()
```

Output:

```
total runs of 1
waiter1 waited for 1 seconds
total runs of 1
waiter2 waited for 1 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator can be any callable.

In your code, you used the class `decorator` itself (and not an instance thereof) as the decorator. In this case, the `__init__` method of the `decorator` class is invoked with the decorated function as an argument.

In order to use an instance of the class as a decorator, you would have to replace the decoration `@decorator` with `@decorator()`. That would cause the invocation of the `__call__` method of a `decorator` instance with the decorated function as an argument. Of course, you would have to adapt the signature of the `__call__` method.

Comment: Could you add some code to demonstrate? I'm not sure how that would work.